# Sequelize not storing additional Join Table Fields

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, sequelize.js

I have two models with a many-to-many association. I've created an additional model for the join table so I can store data with the join table.

Now the association works fine but the data which should be stored in the join table is not persisted to the database.

I have a separate class for each Model which abstracts the sequelize api away.

Through debugging I've noticed that the dataValues of the sequelize model are set correctly but sequelize only runs a Select query instead of an update query.
I guess the Select query is to check whether the data is already inserted because the associated model is not fetched from the database but build from the http post body.

Maybe this happens because of my model but I'm not sure where the error is.
Any idea's?

**DAO 1**

```
export const ProjectModel: Sequelize.Model<IProjectInstance, IProjectModel> = db.define<IProjectInstance, IProjectModel>('project', {
    privateTitle: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    },
    publicTitle: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    }
}, {
    defaultScope: {
        include: [
            {
                model: ProfileModel,
                as: 'coworkers',
                include: [
                    {
                        model: UserModel,
                        as: 'user'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});


ProjectModel.belongsToMany(ProfileModel, {
    as: 'coworkers',
    through: ProjectProfileModel,
    foreignKey: 'projectId',
    otherKey: 'profileId'
});
```

**DAO 2**

```
export const ProfileModel: Sequelize.Model<IProfileInstance, IProfileModel> = db.define<IProfileInstance, IProfileModel>('profile', {
    label: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    userId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: UserModel,
            key: 'id'
        }
    }
}, {
    scopes: {
        user: {
            include: [
                {
                    model: UserModel,
                    as: 'user'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

**Join DAO**

```
export const ProjectProfileModel: Sequelize.Model<IProjectProfileInstance, IProjectProfileModel> = db.define<IProjectProfileInstance, IProjectProfileModel>('projectProfile', {
    start: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
    },
    end: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: true
    },
    role: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    }
});
```

**Model 1**

```
export class Project implements IModel {
    private _model: IProjectInstance;
    private _coworkers: Coworker[];

    public static async get(number: number, scope?: string): Promise<Project> {
        const Model = scope ? ProjectModel.scope(scope) : ProjectModel;
        return Model
            .findOne({
                where: {
                    number: number
                }
            })
            .then(project => new Project(project));
    }

    public static assignable: string[] = ['id', 'coworkers'];

    constructor(data: (IProjectInstance | IProjectObject), instance?: IProjectInstance) {
        if (isInstance(data)) {
            this._model = data;
            this._customer = data.customer ? new Customer(data.customer) : undefined;
        }else if (instance) {
            this._model = instance;
        }else {
            this._model = ProjectModel.build();
        }
        if (!isInstance(data)) {
            assign(this, data, Project.assignable);
        }
    }

    public get coworkers(): Coworker[] {
        if (this._coworkers === undefined) {
            this._coworkers = map(this._model.coworkers,
                coworker => new Coworker(coworker, this.id));
        }
        return this._coworkers;
    }

    public set coworkers(value: Coworker[]) {
        this._coworkers = map(value, profile => profile instanceof Coworker ? profile : new Coworker(profile, this.id));
    }

    public async save(): Promise<Project> {
        await db.transaction(async (transaction) => {
            await this._model.setCoworkers(map(this._coworkers, (coworker: Coworker) => coworker.model), { transaction });
            await this._model.save({ transaction });
        });
        return this;
    }

    public async delete(): Promise<void> {
        return this._model.destroy();
    }
}
```

**Model 2**

```
export class Profile implements IModel {
    private _model: IProfileInstance;

    constructor(data: (IProfileInstance | IProfileObject )) {
        if (isInstance(data)) {
            this._model = data;
        }else {
            this._model = ProfileModel.build();
            assign(this, data, ['id', 'label', 'user', 'userId']);
        }
    }


    public async save(): Promise<Profile> {
        await this._model.save();
        return this;
    }

    public async delete(): Promise<void> {
        return this._model.destroy();
    }
}
```

**Association Model**

```
export class Coworker extends Profile {

    constructor(data, project) {
        super(data);
        if (!isInstance(data)) {
            this.model.projectProfile = ProjectProfileModel.build();
            this.projectId = project;
            assign(this, data);
        }
    }

    public get id(): number {
        return this.model.id;
    }

    public set id(value: number) {
        this.model.id = value;
        if (this.model.projectProfile !== undefined) {
            this.model.projectProfile.profileId = value;
        }
    }

    public get profileId(): number {
        return this.model.projectProfile.profileId;
    }

    public set profileId(value: number) {
        this.model.projectProfile.profileId = value;
    }

    public get projectId(): number {
        return this.model.projectProfile.projectId;
    }

    public set projectId(value: number) {
        this.model.projectProfile.projectId = value;
    }

    public get start(): Date {
        return this.model.projectProfile.start;
    }

    public set start(value: Date) {
        this.model.projectProfile.start = value;
    }

    public get end(): Date {
        return this.model.projectProfile.end;
    }

    public set end(value: Date) {
        this.model.projectProfile.end = value;
    }

    public get role(): string {
        return this.model.projectProfile.role;
    }

    public set role(value: string) {
        this.model.projectProfile.role = value;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
function update(req, res, next) {
    Project.get(req.param.id)
        .then(project => assign(project, req.body))
        .then(project => project.save())
        .then(project => {
            res.json(project);
            res.status(200);
            res.end();
        })
        .catch(err => next(err));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the fix was pretty simple. The association property on the model has to be an object instead of a Sequelize Instance.
The association model below contains the fixed constructor.

```
export class Coworker extends Profile {

    constructor(data, project) {
        super(data);
        if (!isInstance(data)) {
            this.model.projectProfile = {};
            this.projectId = project;
            assign(this, data);
        }
    }

    public get id(): number {
        return this.model.id;
    }

    public set id(value: number) {
        this.model.id = value;
        if (this.model.projectProfile !== undefined) {
            this.model.projectProfile.profileId = value;
        }
    }

    public get profileId(): number {
        return this.model.projectProfile.profileId;
    }

    public set profileId(value: number) {
        this.model.projectProfile.profileId = value;
    }

    public get projectId(): number {
        return this.model.projectProfile.projectId;
    }

    public set projectId(value: number) {
        this.model.projectProfile.projectId = value;
    }

    public get start(): Date {
        return this.model.projectProfile.start;
    }

    public set start(value: Date) {
        this.model.projectProfile.start = value;
    }

    public get end(): Date {
        return this.model.projectProfile.end;
    }

    public set end(value: Date) {
        this.model.projectProfile.end = value;
    }

    public get role(): string {
        return this.model.projectProfile.role;
    }

    public set role(value: string) {
        this.model.projectProfile.role = value;
    }
}
```